# how to duplicate objects using X,Y coordinates

Tags: verilog, fpga

for a college project we need to make SPACE INVADERS like game in verilog using FPGA. As part of the game we need to create a matrix of "monsters" which we control, how can we do it?

We got a VGA module which we send RGB preferences and coordinates via Bitmap module. 
We want to create a matrix by duplicate one object to multiple objects that move together as one but we can control them separately (can give any of them different color, enable, etc...)

We add the create_matrix module that we need to change in order to display the full matrix (we can, and probably should, use div and mod operation, however we don't really know how). Now it displays only one.

```
module  create_matrix   (   
                    input       logic   clk,
                    input       logic   resetN,
                    input   logic   [10:0] pixelX,// current VGA pixel 
                    input   logic   [10:0] pixelY,
                    input   logic   [10:0] topLeftX, //position on the screen 
                    input   logic   [10:0] topLeftY,

                    input   logic enable,   

                    output  logic   [10:0] offsetX,// offset inside bracket from top left position 
                    output  logic   [10:0] offsetY,
                    output  logic   drawingRequest, // indicates pixel inside the bracket
                    output  logic   [7:0]    RGBout //optional color output for mux 
);

parameter  int OBJECT_WIDTH_X=100;
parameter  int OBJECT_HEIGHT_Y=100;
parameter  logic [7:0] OBJECT_COLOR=8'b11111111; 

localparam logic [7:0] TRANSPARENT_ENCODING = 8'hFF ;// bitmap  representation for a transparent pixel 

int rightX ; //coordinates of the sides  
int bottomY ;
logic insideBracket ; 

// Calculate object right  & bottom  boundaries
assign rightX   = (topLeftX + OBJECT_WIDTH_X);
assign bottomY  = (topLeftY + OBJECT_HEIGHT_Y);


always_ff@(posedge clk or negedge resetN)
begin
    if(!resetN) begin
        RGBout          <=  8'b0;
        drawingRequest  <=  1'b0;
    end
    else begin 

    insideBracket  =     ( (pixelX  >= topLeftX) &&  (pixelX < rightX)  
                           && (pixelY  >= topLeftY) &&  (pixelY < bottomY) )  ; 

        if (insideBracket && enable==1'b1) // test if it is inside the rectangle 
        begin 
            RGBout  <= OBJECT_COLOR ;   // colors table 
            drawingRequest <= 1'b1 ;
            offsetX <= (pixelX - topLeftX); //calculate relative offsets from top left corner
            offsetY <= (pixelY - topLeftY);
        end 

        else begin  
            RGBout <= TRANSPARENT_ENCODING ; // so it will not be displayed 
            drawingRequest <= 1'b0 ;// transparent color 
            offsetX <= 0; //no offset
            offsetY <= 0; //no offset
        end 

    end
end 
endmodule
```

Thank you very much for helping us

Answer (score 0):

you can't describe a synthesizable `n*n` matrix. you need to fill the pixels data in a RAM with correct indexing, which may be described as an [0:n*n] array. (e.g. if you have a 5*5 image you need a RAM with the size of 25.

`reg [word_size : 0] RAM [0:25];`

it's better to avoid using mod operation because it may probably take to much hardware size. I think it's possible to avoid it with correct indexing and some changes in your controller state machine.

I couldn't take any hardware impression from your code. do you have any RTL design on paper? If not I absolutely encourage you to first design your circuit on paper then start to implement it.

(this post was supposed to be a comment but my reputation didn't allow me to comment on your question. I'll update the answer when more information provided.)